# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in owlready library

Tags: python, sparql, semantic-web, owlready

I'm trying to query data with python in the owl file I created using the owlready library. But I get the following error. what would be the reason?

The code structure and received error are as follows.

```
from owlready2 import *
from urllib.request import urlopen
from rdflib.graph import Graph

onto = default_world.get_ontology("http://muratkilinc.com/ontologies/izmir.owl").load()

graph = default_world.as_rdflib_graph()
r = list(graph.query_owlready("""
    PREFIX uni:<http://muratkilinc.com/ontologies/izmir.owl>
    SELECT ?adi ?soyadi ?yas
    WHERE
    {
        ?turistler uni:yas ?yas.
        ?turistler uni:adi ?adi.
        ?turistler uni:soyadi ?soyadi.
        FILTER(?yas > 35).

    }"""))

results = default_world.as_rdflib_graph().query_owlready(r)
results = list(results)
print(results)
```

**Error:**

```
* Owlready2 * Warning: optimized Cython parser module 'owlready2_optimized' is not available, 
defaulting to slower Python implementation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/BAUM-PC/Desktop/izmir/sparql.py", line 21, in <module>
    results = list(results)
  File "C:\Users\BAUM-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\owlready2\rdflib_store.py", line 261, in query_owlready
  File "C:\Users\BAUM-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\rdflib\graph.py", line 1089, in query
    query_object, initBindings, initNs, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\BAUM-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\rdflib\plugins\sparql\processor.py", line 74, in query
    parsetree = parseQuery(strOrQuery)
  File "C:\Users\BAUM-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\rdflib\plugins\sparql\parser.py", line 1057, in parseQuery
    q = expandUnicodeEscapes(q)
  File "C:\Users\BAUM-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\rdflib\plugins\sparql\parser.py", line 1048, in expandUnicodeEscapes
    return expandUnicodeEscapes_re.sub(expand, q)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: it looks like you do the same thing two times - first time you use string as argument but in second time you put result from previous line as argument. Maybe you should't do it second time and do only `print( r )`.

Comment: you may be right.however,even though the result of the sparql query is full,I only get an empty result of " [ ] " when I try with `print (r)`. as if it does not list the results of the sparql query. @furas

Comment: but it resolve your problem with error. Now you have different problem and it would need to create new question. Maybe this query simply can't get any result and you have to change query. I don't know OWL files but with query for SQL database I would use any tool to work with database and try query in this tool to see what result it will give.

Comment: OR maybe start with simpler query - without `WHERE` - to see if you get anything. And then start to adding single elements in `WHERE` to test which can make problem.

Comment: I'm trying to run a fairly simple query. I see the same error there. I think it's about something else. @furas

Comment: your error message was resolved - you have to use only one `query_owlready`. Your current problem is only query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to skip second query and error message will skip

```
from owlready2 import *
from rdflib.graph import Graph

onto = default_world.get_ontology("http://muratkilinc.com/ontologies/izmir.owl").load()

graph = default_world.as_rdflib_graph()

r = list(graph.query_owlready("""
    PREFIX uni:<http://muratkilinc.com/ontologies/izmir.owl>
    SELECT ?adi ?soyadi ?yas
    WHERE
    {
        ?turistler uni:yas ?yas.
        ?turistler uni:adi ?adi.
        ?turistler uni:soyadi ?soyadi.
        FILTER(?yas > 35).
    }"""))

print(list(r))
```

It gives empty list - so it works without error message.

Empty list is different problem - with query, not with code - so you should ask new question.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I will try to settle the status of the query empty. at least the code part doesn't make any errors right now.